# Continuously update database without overloading the server

Tags: database, multithreading

I have to maintain ranking of some records in my DB which change dependents on time of the last interaction.

```
Post
______________
Id    
Content
LastAccessTime
LastRankedTime
Rank
```

I am thinking about periodically visit the DB and get all Posts with LastRankedTime > 15 Minutes

Then apply Rank() on each item before writing them all back to DB

Do I have to worry about the long ranking calculation or big read/write overloading my server/DB if i have to do the ranking on >10.000 records?

What is a better approach to this problem?
How will a throttled thread with limited number of record per Db visits help?

Comment: depending which database you are using, there may be a mechanism for this kind of thing already. In SQL Server for example there is `ROWVERSION` which can tell you whether a row has been updated since you last looked at it.

Comment: But i still have to pull the record out to re-do the ranking since it is dependent on other metrics also. So maybe that will not help much in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what database you use, there can be multiple database nodes and you can think of clusterred database.

You only write your data in one node. This will have no indexing in tables. Which makes the insertion faster. You dont read from this node.

In the mean time the other node is only for read purpose with lots of indexing done for faster search.

First node will periodically sync / replicate data to the other nodes. You can configure interval for such synchronization. This is the standard approach, that is usually followed in large architecture with heavy traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I end up using background workers with simple limited i/o. In the case the DB become unexpectedly large i will look into this solution

Answer (score -1):

create  indexes on the columns you are using it will work fine

Comment: Can you provide more detailed answer how will indexes help in this particular case?